# Ant: add a single compiled class file to javac classpath?

Tags: java, ant, classpath, javac

In Ant, if I have a lone compiled CLASS file located somewhere inside my project (say at `gen/stragglers/SomePOJO.class`, is there a way to specifically add that class file to my `<javac>` compile classpath, when I currently have the following:

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src/main/java"
        destdir="gen/bin/main">
    <classpath refid="main.compile.path"/>
</javac>
```

If not, why? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Builld a path refering your class file :

```
<path id="javac.classpath">
     <pathelement location="./gen/stragglers/SomePOJO.class"/>
</path>
```

Then use it within your javac task :

```
<javac srcdir="./src/main/java" destdir="./gen/bin/main">
    <classpath refid="javac.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't add a single class file as such, you add a *directory* to the classpath and the compiler will look for classes under that directory at relative paths derived from their package structure.  This is not negotiable as far as I know - the directory structure *must* match the package structure.

So for example, if the class defined in `SomePOJO.class` is `stragglers.SomePOJO` then you'd add the `gen` directory to the classpath

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src/main/java"
        destdir="gen/bin/main">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="gen" />
      <path refid="main.compile.path"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

If the path to the `.class` file doesn't match the `package` declaration of the class then you'll have to move it into a temporary directory that *does* match the package structure, and then add that directory to the classpath instead.